# Hasura order by date with distinct

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have a course table, each course has an id, a code and a start date. Example:

```
course_id    course_code    start_date
uuid1        course_a       2021-06-01
uuid2        course_a       2021-09-01
uuid3        course_b       2021-06-01
uuid4        course_b       2021-09-01
```

I want to get the latest record of each distinct course and I can do it in SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (course_code)
    course_id,
    course_code,
    start_date
FROM course
ORDER BY course_code, start_date DESC

uuid2        course_a       2021-09-01
uuid4        course_b       2021-09-01
```

But is it possible to query in graphql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding a list of order_by condition instead of unordered object

```
query MyQuery {
  course(distinct_on: course_code, order_by: [{course_code: asc}, {start_date: desc}]) {
    course_id
    course_code,
    start_date
  }
}
```